# Why is my .bashrc not read under cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin, bashrc

My .bashrc looks like this:

```
alias name@server="ssh server sname"
echo "bashrc read"
```

The `echo` statement is just for checking if it is read. But the echo does nothing. I want to set an alias for a quicker ssh into a box doing a certain command which is a working alias on the remote box.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't used cygwin in some time, but I'm guessing that it wants ~/.bash_profile. Simple fix to test.

```
ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```

Or if ~/.bash_profile exists, source .bashrc.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: I added a .bash_profile and put the source part in it. Worked... Thx

Answer (score 3):

Because your cygwin bash is a login shell which reads the profile files, not the rc files. See jtimberman's answer for the second part of the answer... .

Answer (score 1):

as jtimberman said, it's probably using `.bash_profile`. Another one to remember about is `.profile`.

Comment: Exactly! In my case on Windows 7 .bashrc is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the ip. simply add the "ipaddress sname" to your C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts files and it should resolved it.

example: 127.0.0.1 localhost
         [ipaddress sname]

Comment: ohh you might need to type in "source .bashrc" to get it to reload the alias... :)